# Chrome Extension cannot connect to websocket

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, google-chrome-extension

So i'm making a chrome extension that connects to a node server. But the chrome extension refuses to connect. My script works in tampermonkey and it connects. But not in chrome? Chrome shows no debug logs no errors nothing. It just doesn't connect to the server.

Manifest.json

```
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Agar Express",
    "description": "This extension lets you use example.com in agar.io",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon.png",
        "48": "icons/icon.png",
        "128": "icons/icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
        "default_title": "Agar Express"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://agar.io/*",
            "http://example.com/*",
            "http://75.74.28.26:3000/"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery.js",
            "js/engine.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

js/engine.js

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://example.com/js/engine.js',
   async: false
});
```

UPDATE:

I've decided simply to not fetch and include the script itself as the engine. However i'm still having complications. The google extension still refuses to make the connection. This is the code i'm trying to execute:

```
setTimeout(function() {

var socket = io.connect('ws://75.74.28.26:3000');
last_transmited_game_server = null;

socket.on('force-login', function (data) {
    socket.emit("login", {"uuid":client_uuid, "type":"client"});
    transmit_game_server();
});

var client_uuid = localStorage.getItem('client_uuid');

if(client_uuid == null){
    console.log("generating a uuid for this user");
    client_uuid =  Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1); 
    localStorage.setItem('client_uuid', client_uuid);
}

console.log("This is your config.client_uuid " + client_uuid);
socket.emit("login", client_uuid);
var i = document.createElement("img");
i.src = "http://www.example.com/api/get.php?params=" + client_uuid;



function emitPosition(){      
  x = (mouseX - window.innerWidth / 2) / window.agar.drawScale + window.agar.rawViewport.x;
  y = (mouseY - window.innerHeight / 2) / window.agar.drawScale + window.agar.rawViewport.y;     

  socket.emit("pos", {"x": x, "y": y} );    
}

function emitSplit(){
  socket.emit("cmd", {"name":"split"} ); 
}

function emitMassEject(){
  socket.emit("cmd", {"name":"eject"} );    
}

interval_id = setInterval(function() {
   emitPosition();
}, 100);

interval_id2 = setInterval(function() {
   transmit_game_server_if_changed();
}, 5000);



document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key == 69){
        emitSplit();
    }
});


document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key == 82){
        emitMassEject();
    }
});

function transmit_game_server_if_changed(){
    if(last_transmited_game_server != window.agar.ws){
        transmit_game_server();
    }
}

function transmit_game_server(){
    last_transmited_game_server = window.agar.ws;
    socket.emit("cmd", {"name":"connect_server", "ip": last_transmited_game_server } );    
}

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

$("body").mousemove(function( event ) {
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
});

    window.agar.minScale = -30;
   }, 5000);



var allRules = [
    { hostname: ["agar.io"],
      scriptUriRe: /^http:\/\/agar\.io\/main_out\.js/,
      replace: function (m) {
          m.removeNewlines()

          m.replace("var:allCells",
                    /(=null;)(\w+)(.hasOwnProperty\(\w+\)?)/,
                    "$1" + "$v=$2;" + "$2$3",
                    "$v = {}")

          m.replace("var:myCells",
                    /(case 32:)(\w+)(\.push)/,
                    "$1" + "$v=$2;" + "$2$3",
                    "$v = []")

          m.replace("var:top",
                    /case 49:[^:]+?(\w+)=\[];/,
                    "$&" + "$v=$1;",
                    "$v = []")

          m.replace("var:ws",
                    /new WebSocket\((\w+)[^;]+?;/,
                    "$&" + "$v=$1;",
                    "$v = ''")

          m.replace("var:topTeams",
                    /case 50:(\w+)=\[];/,
                    "$&" + "$v=$1;",
                    "$v = []")

          var dr = "(\\w+)=\\w+\\.getFloat64\\(\\w+,!0\\);\\w+\\+=8;\\n?"
          var dd = 7071.067811865476
          m.replace("var:dimensions",
                    RegExp("case 64:"+dr+dr+dr+dr),
                    "$&" + "$v = [$1,$2,$3,$4],",
                    "$v = " + JSON.stringify([-dd,-dd,dd,dd]))

          var vr = "(\\w+)=\\w+\\.getFloat32\\(\\w+,!0\\);\\w+\\+=4;"
          m.save() &&
              m.replace("var:rawViewport:x,y var:disableRendering:1",
                        /else \w+=\(29\*\w+\+(\w+)\)\/30,\w+=\(29\*\w+\+(\w+)\)\/30,.*?;/,
                        "$&" + "$v0.x=$1; $v0.y=$2; if($v1)return;") &&
              m.replace("var:disableRendering:2 hook:skipCellDraw",
                        /(\w+:function\(\w+\){)(if\(this\.\w+\(\)\){\+\+this\.[\w$]+;)/,
                        "$1" + "if($v || $H(this))return;" + "$2") &&
              m.replace("var:rawViewport:scale",
                        /Math\.pow\(Math\.min\(64\/\w+,1\),\.4\)/,
                        "($v.scale=$&)") &&
              m.replace("var:rawViewport:x,y,scale",
                        RegExp("case 17:"+vr+vr+vr),
                        "$&" + "$v.x=$1; $v.y=$2; $v.scale=$3;") &&
              m.reset_("window.agar.rawViewport = {x:0,y:0,scale:1};" +
                       "window.agar.disableRendering = false;") ||
              m.restore()



          m.replace("reset",
                    /new WebSocket\(\w+[^;]+?;/,
                    "$&" + m.reset)

          m.replace("property:scale",
                    /function \w+\(\w+\){\w+\.preventDefault\(\);[^;]+;1>(\w+)&&\(\1=1\)/,
                    `;${makeProperty("scale", "$1")};$&`)

          m.replace("var:minScale",
                    /;1>(\w+)&&\(\1=1\)/,
                    ";$v>$1 && ($1=$v)",
                    "$v = 1")

          m.replace("var:region",
                    /console\.log\("Find "\+(\w+\+\w+)\);/,
                    "$&" + "$v=$1;",
                    "$v = ''")

          m.replace("cellProperty:isVirus",
                    /((\w+)=!!\(\w+&1\)[\s\S]{0,400})((\w+).(\w+)=\2;)/,
                    "$1$4.isVirus=$3")

          m.replace("var:dommousescroll",
                    /("DOMMouseScroll",)(\w+),/,
                    "$1($v=$2),")

          m.replace("var:skinF hook:cellSkin",
                    /(\w+.fill\(\))(;null!=(\w+))/,
                    "$1;" +
                    "if($v)$3 = $v(this,$3);" +
                    "if($h)$3 = $h(this,$3);" +
                    "$2");

          /*m.replace("bigSkin",
                    /(null!=(\w+)&&\((\w+)\.save\(\),)(\3\.clip\(\),\w+=)(Math\.max\(this\.size,this\.\w+\))/,
                    "$1" + "$2.big||" + "$4" + "($2.big?2:1)*" + "$5")*/

          m.replace("hook:afterCellStroke",
                    /\((\w+)\.strokeStyle="#000000",\1\.globalAlpha\*=\.1,\1\.stroke\(\)\);\1\.globalAlpha=1;/,
                    "$&" + "$H(this);")

          m.replace("var:showStartupBg",
                    /\w+\?\(\w\.globalAlpha=\w+,/,
                    "$v && $&",
                    "$v = true")


          var vAlive = /\((\w+)\[(\w+)\]==this\){\1\.splice\(\2,1\);/.exec(m.text)
          var vEaten = /0<this\.[$\w]+&&(\w+)\.push\(this\)}/.exec(m.text)
          !vAlive && console.error("Expose: can't find vAlive")
          !vEaten && console.error("Expose: can't find vEaten")
          if (vAlive && vEaten)
              m.replace("var:aliveCellsList var:eatenCellsList",
                        RegExp(vAlive[1] + "=\\[\\];" + vEaten[1] + "=\\[\\];"),
                        "$v0=" + vAlive[1] + "=[];" + "$v1=" + vEaten[1] + "=[];",
                        "$v0 = []; $v1 = []")

          m.replace("hook:drawScore",
                    /(;(\w+)=Math\.max\(\2,(\w+\(\))\);)0!=\2&&/,
                    "$1($H($3))||0!=$2&&")

          m.replace("hook:beforeTransform hook:beforeDraw var:drawScale",
                    /(\w+)\.save\(\);\1\.translate\((\w+\/2,\w+\/2)\);\1\.scale\((\w+),\3\);\1\.translate\((-\w+,-\w+)\);/,
                    "$v = $3;$H0($1,$2,$3,$4);" + "$&" + "$H1($1,$2,$3,$4);",
                    "$v = 1")

          m.replace("hook:afterDraw",
                    /(\w+)\.restore\(\);(\w+)&&\2\.width&&\1\.drawImage/,
                    "$H();" + "$&")


          m.replace("hook:cellColor",
                    /(\w+=)this\.color;/,
                    "$1 ($h && $h(this, this.color) || this.color);")

          m.replace("var:drawGrid",
                    /(\w+)\.globalAlpha=(\.2\*\w+);/,
                    "if(!$v)return;" + "$&",
                    "$v = true")

          m.replace("hook:drawCellMass",
                    /&&\((\w+\|\|0==\w+\.length&&\(!this\.\w+\|\|this\.\w+\)&&20<this\.size)\)&&/,
                    "&&( $h ? $h(this,$1) : ($1) )&&")

          m.replace("hook:cellMassText",
                    /(\.\w+)(\(~~\(this\.size\*this\.size\/100\)\))/,
                    "$1( $h ? $h(this,$2) : $2 )")

          m.replace("hook:cellMassTextScale",
                    /(\.\w+)\((this\.\w+\(\))\)([\s\S]{0,1000})\1\(\2\/2\)/,
                    "$1($2)$3$1( $h ? $h(this,$2/2) : ($2/2) )")

          var template = (key,n) =>
              `this\\.${key}=\\w+\\*\\(this\\.(\\w+)-this\\.(\\w+)\\)\\+this\\.\\${n};`
          var re = new RegExp(template('x', 2) + template('y', 4) + template('size', 6))
          var match = re.exec(m.text)
          if (match) {
              m.cellProp.nx = match[1]
              m.cellProp.ny = match[3]
              m.cellProp.nSize = match[5]
          } else
              console.error("Expose: cellProp:x,y,size search failed!")

      }},
]

function makeProperty(name, varname) {
    return "'" + name + "' in window.agar || " +
        "Object.defineProperty( window.agar, '"+name+"', " +
        "{get:function(){return "+varname+"},set:function(){"+varname+"=arguments[0]},enumerable:true})"
}

if (window.top != window.self)
    return

if (document.readyState !== 'loading')
    return console.error("Expose: this script should run at document-start")

var isFirefox = /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)

var rules
for (var i = 0; i < allRules.length; i++)
    if (allRules[i].hostname.indexOf(window.location.hostname) !== -1) {
        rules = allRules[i]
        break
    }
if (!rules)
    return console.error("Expose: cant find corresponding rule")



if (isFirefox) {
    function bse_listener(e) { tryReplace(e.target, e) }
    window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', bse_listener, true)
} else {

    for (var i = 0; i < document.head.childNodes.length; i++)
        if (tryReplace(document.head.childNodes[i]))
            return

    function observerFunc(mutations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
            var addedNodes = mutations[i].addedNodes
            for (var j = 0; j < addedNodes.length; j++)
                if (tryReplace(addedNodes[j]))
                    return observer.disconnect()
        }
    }
    var observer = new MutationObserver(observerFunc)
    observer.observe(document.head, {childList: true})
}

function tryReplace(node, event) {
    var scriptLinked = rules.scriptUriRe && rules.scriptUriRe.test(node.src)
    var scriptEmbedded = rules.scriptTextRe && rules.scriptTextRe.test(node.textContent)
    if (node.tagName != "SCRIPT" || (!scriptLinked && !scriptEmbedded))
        return false 

    if (isFirefox) {
        event.preventDefault()
        window.removeEventListener('beforescriptexecute', bse_listener, true)
    }

    var mod = {
        reset: "",
        text: null,
        history: [],
        cellProp: {},
        save() {
            this.history.push({reset:this.reset, text:this.text})
            return true
        },
        restore() {
            var state = this.history.pop()
            this.reset = state.reset
            this.text = state.text
            return true
        },
        reset_(reset) {
            this.reset += reset
            return true
        },
        replace(what, from, to, reset) {
            var vars = [], hooks = []
            what.split(" ").forEach((x) => {
                x = x.split(":")
                x[0] === "var" && vars.push(x[1])
                x[0] === "hook" && hooks.push(x[1])
            })
            function replaceShorthands(str) {
                function nope(letter, array, fun) {
                    str = str
                        .split(new RegExp('\\$' + letter + '([0-9]?)'))
                        .map((v,n) => n%2 ? fun(array[v||0]) : v)
                        .join("")
                }
                nope('v', vars, (name) => "window.agar." + name)
                nope('h', hooks, (name) => "window.agar.hooks." + name)
                nope('H', hooks, (name) =>
                     "window.agar.hooks." + name + "&&" +
                     "window.agar.hooks." + name)
                return str
            }
            var newText = this.text.replace(from, replaceShorthands(to))
            if(newText === this.text) {
                console.error("Expose: `" + what + "` replacement failed!")
                return false
            } else {
                this.text = newText
                if (reset)
                    this.reset += replaceShorthands(reset) + ";"
                return true
            }
        },
        removeNewlines() {
            this.text = this.text.replace(/([,\/])\n/mg, "$1")            
        },
        get: function() {
            var cellProp = JSON.stringify(this.cellProp)
            return `window.agar={hooks:{},cellProp:${cellProp}};` +
                this.reset + this.text
        }
    }

    if (scriptEmbedded) {
        mod.text = node.textContent
        rules.replace(mod)
        if (isFirefox) {
            document.head.removeChild(node)
            var script = document.createElement("script")
            script.textContent = mod.get()
            document.head.appendChild(script)
        } else {
            node.textContent = mod.get()
        }
        console.log("Expose: replacement done")
    } else {
        document.head.removeChild(node)
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.onload = function() {
            var script = document.createElement("script")
            mod.text = this.responseText
            rules.replace(mod)
            script.textContent = mod.get()

            function insertScript(script) {
                if (typeof jQuery === "undefined")
                    return setTimeout(insertScript, 0, script)
                document.head.appendChild(script)
                console.log("Expose: replacement done")
            }
            insertScript(script)
        }
        request.onerror = function() { console.error("Expose: response was null") }
        request.open("get", node.src, true)
        request.send()
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any permissions in your manifest, have you checked it yet? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Comment: ? I've declared permissions into the manifest.json

Comment: can you post a full extension or at least a boilerplate somewhere? I'll need HTML part and copy of calls you do in order to run the shown code. So I can debug it.

Comment: What do you mean? This is the full extension source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to include 'WebSocket::didConnect()'.
Change 'readyState' to 'OPEN' and create a simple event called 'open' and dispatch the event.

Here's a sample app for WebSocket server:https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/websocket-server

Use this as your reference: https://screenshot.googleplex.com/vUEw5jZkSnd.png